# JPA add Listener Programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA(Hibernate) Project with Entities created from XML orm.xml and Beans, i have a EntityManager with update,persist,remove,findById,findAll methods but i need add a Filter Listener to check the Beans before and after save, restore, etc. (i need set to null some values to return to client)

My question is how to add "Programatically" add a Listener with @PrePersist, @PreUpdate @.., to all Entities.

regards.

Comment: Why the downvote?, i have the same question, i need to add some listeners depending on a config file which is loaded when the app starts

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but maybe something like this would help you:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @PreUpdate
    public abstract void preUpdate();
}


public class YourEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @Override
    public void preUpdate() {
       Do something here...
    }
}
```

This should work like a "hook method", but again, that's only an idea.

Comment: Thanks D Rodrigues, but i have the entities and my target is over the entities add the listeners. programmatically from the entity manager.